# file_get_contents fails, but POST request is made successfully

Tags: php, http-post, file-get-contents

#### spoiler* convoluted code ahead

## Context

*main.php* has a command-line like input, the file's form **action** attribute is *submit.php*. *submit.php* decides what other file to call, based on the input from *main.php*. In *submit.php* I adjust variables $**url** and $**data**, based on the input, then call **file_get_contents** with these parameters.

With post requests that do not have session headers I do not have any problem, but once I needed these and tried sending them, I hit a roadblock:

- the function *file_get_contents* itself fails.
- the request made by the function is completed successfully

## Example and Symptoms

I hit submit on *main.php* to call *submit.php* with parameters to make a post request for *list/access/index.php*:

- Server hangs until timeout
- On timeout I get the following output.

  Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/example/list/access/index.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /Users/josetaveras/Sites/example/php_toolbox/toolbox.php on line 83

  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/josetaveras/Sites/example/php_toolbox/toolbox.php:83) in /Users/josetaveras/Sites/example/list/submit.php on line 373

When I go back to my *main.php* I know the post request is completed successfully because the request made in *list/access/index.php* simply sets a session variable. This variable is visible when going back to *main.php*.

## Relevant code

*submit.php*

```
$result = post_request($url,$data,$headers);
header(
            'Location: '
            .$root_folder_path
            .'list/?h='
            .$hash
            );}
// after post_request we get back to main.php with simple header redirect
```

*toolbox.php*

```
/*
*   recursive merging 2 arrays
*/
function rec_array_merge($ar1,$ar2){
    foreach($ar2 as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            if(isset($ar1[$k])){
                $ar1[$k] = rec_array_merge($ar1[$k],$v);
            }else{
                $ar1[$k]=$v;
            }
        }else{
            $ar1[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $ar1;
}
function serialize_array($array,$map_symbol,$separator_symbol){
    $returnstr = "";
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $returnstr.=$k.$map_symbol.$v.$separator_symbol;
    }
    return $returnstr;
}
function post_request($url,$data,$headers=NULL){
    $post_content = http_build_query($data);
    $default_headers = Array(
        "Content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ,"Content-Length"=>strlen($post_content)
        );

    if(isset($headers)){
        try{
            $headers = rec_array_merge($default_headers,$headers);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            print_r($e);
        }
    }else{
        $headers = $default_headers;
        }
    $serialized = serialize_array($headers,": ","\r\n");
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => $serialized
            ,'method'  => 'POST'
            ,'content' => $post_content
            ,'timeout' => 1 // for debugging purposes
            )
        );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); // line 83 on toolbox.php

    return $result;
}
```

## References

I used [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) to construct my post_request.

## Final thoughts

It is redundant to say that I am not so deft with PHP, and I know and understand that I have bad habits. This leads to a little bit of disorder in the code and many poor choices. My impression is that overall this *pattern* feels fragile. I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, but I am pointedly avoiding libraries and packages that facilitate any part of this. I understand that a routing package might help me with all of this.
I appreciate any feedback you may have on this question. All criticism is welcome and I will try to answer as soon as I can but I have limited connectivity and access to my computing devices. Having said all of that, thank you for reading up to this point.

Comment: Can you post sample input data for `post_request($url,$data,$headers);` If you followed that post it might be an issue for your data being used.

Comment: Also try reading the comments from the post you are following. "do NOT end the keys or values with '\r\n' "

Comment: Does this only happen with 'session-headers'  or with _any_ additional headers? What do you do in `...list/access/index.php` with the (additional session) headers?

Comment: @Jeff it does only seem to happen with 'session-headers'. I use them to save a session variable to "access" some information (like saving a hashed password in the session)

Comment: I've limited myself to adding a timeout = 1 on the post_request and I'm avoiding the hangup. this seems hacky as cheese but I'm not ready to put a bounty on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months I finally found the reason why this was happening. 
The worst aspect of this is that I am familiar with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini('error_notice',1)` but I completely forgot about it. I did learn about `var_dump($http_response_header)` so there is that.
Honestly it was in the documentation and I should have found it sooner. Oh well.

I quote myself

> With post requests that do not have session headers I do not have any problem, but once I needed these and tried sending them, I hit a roadblock

I was not familiar exactly with how session mechanics work in general, so i mostly ignored the documentation until I found it a few minutes ago. I refer to [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) as what I should have read before diving into sessions (or more specifically, attempting to open multiple sessions in a chain of requests (that I thought of as a single request)):

> session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time

In my *submit.php* I open the session to access some variables. I basically forgot to close it before making a new request which itself attempted to modify session data. The fix was to use `session_write_close()` right before `post_request()`.

Thank you to all who commented.